# image in IOS onesignal notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

How can I create a notification like 
[IOS notification with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SvME.png)

It is said that you can not specify icon for the IOS but how does this app do it?

I tried with ios_attachments,small_icon,large_icon,big_picture but I did not answer as I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Notification Service Extension` for Push Notification with image. It is a new feature from iOS10. More detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension).

**Steps:**

1. Specify image URL in Payload of push notification like this:

   ```
   {
       "aps" : {
           "alert" : "You got your emails.",
           "badge" : 9,
           "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
       },
       "image_url" : "http://host_name/image.png",
   }
   ```
2. Send Push Notification
3. Upon receiving the push notification, the `Notification Service Extension` is activated before displaying the notification banner, so the image is downloaded and stored in the tmp area using the URL in the payload
4. Notification with the image will be displayed

**Implementation of** `Notification Service Extension`

1. Add `Notification Service Extension`

   - `File > New > Target` in Xcode menu

[image]

- `iOS > Application Extension > Notification Service Extension`

[image]

- `NotificationService.swift` has created.

[image]

2. Implementation of `func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, 
   withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)`

Here the code sample:

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    guard let imageUrl = request.content.userInfo["image_url"] as? String else {
        if let bestAttemptContent = self.bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
        return
    }

    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: imageUrl)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let tempImageFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory())
                .appendingPathComponent("tmp.jpg") {
                try data?.write(to: tempImageFilePath)

                if let bestAttemptContent = self.bestAttemptContent {
                    let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "id", url: tempImageFilePath, options: nil)
                    bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                }
            } else {
                // error: writePath is not URL
                if let bestAttemptContent = self.bestAttemptContent {
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                }
            }
        } catch _ {
            // error: data write error or create UNNotificationAttachment error
            if let bestAttemptContent = self.bestAttemptContent {
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

This enables your app to download the image from `image _ url` in Payload and attach it to the Push Notification.

Comment: i do not see `image_url ` in the doc, are you positive that is the key to use for image attachment like what they have in the website? I tried `image_url `, it did not work